# google maps - marker not moving until I move it manually once

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map on the page http://www.liquidlizard.net/users/trainer

When a user enters a location or postcode in the UK, and clicks search or hits enter then the map is meant to move to that point, which it does but it's meant to take the circle and marker with it. At the moment, only after you've moved the marker by dragging it with the mouse does it then respond properly when you perform a search.

I think it's got something to do with my dragend function but I'm not too great with javascript.

Can anyone help me out?

```
var userLocation = "London";
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var circle;
var latLng;
var marker;
var latlng;
var styles = [
              {
                    stylers: [
                      { hue: "#00ffe6" },
                      { saturation: -20 }
                    ]
              }
            ];

function initialize()
{
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.71194988641549, -0.4821940203124768);

    $('#lattitude').val(51.71194988641549);
    $('#longitude').val(-0.4821940203124768);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        styles: styles,
        center: latlng,
        //panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable:true,
        position: latlng
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        //circle.setVisible(false);
        var point = marker.getPosition();
        map.panTo(point);
        $('#lattitude').val(point.lat());
        $('#longitude').val(point.lng());
        drawCircle($("#miles").val()/0.0621371192*100);
    });
}


$(function(){
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#map-numOf-miles").html(ui.value+' Miles');
            $("#miles").val(ui.value);
            drawCircle(ui.value/0.0621371192*100);
        }
    });
});

function drawCircle(radius) {

    if (circle != undefined)
        circle.setMap(null);

    newlatlong = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($('#lattitude').val()), parseFloat($('#longitude').val()));

    var options = {
        strokeColor: '#d12d87',
        strokeOpacity: 0.35,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#d12d87',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: newlatlong,
        radius: radius
    };

    circle = new google.maps.Circle(options);
}

function geocode(){
 geocoder.geocode({
        address: $('#postcodeViolet').val()+' UK'
    }, function(results, status){
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
         var geoPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            map.setCenter(geoPoint);
            circle.setCenter(geoPoint);
            marker.setPosition(geoPoint);
           $('#lattitude').val(geoPoint.lat());
           $('#longitude').val(geoPoint.lng());
        } else{
            alert("Can not geolocate this address.");
        }
    });
}
```

Also geocode called:

```
//User clicks to search location
$(".spyglassIcon").click(function() {
    geocode();
});

$('.formInputTextPostcode').bind("enterKey",function(e){
    $(".spyglassIcon").click();
});
$('.formInputTextPostcode').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
      $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
});
```

Comment: How is function `geocode()` called? There is no any event listener which wait for changes in `postcodeViolet`.

Comment: Hi Anto - apologies, the code to do that was in another file - it's just simple triggered by a click on the search icon or hits return. I've edited my question. Thanks for taking a look :)

Comment: OK, I set call to `geocode()` with setTimeout. And it works. Marker and circle are moved to the new location. As address I used Cardiff. And I got the same on your live page. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I checked it on Chrome, FF and IE10. Same behaviour. So, I don't know if I understand the problem. I don't see it as you described. BTW, IE10 complains that it is not allowed to put `form` tag into another `form` tag. Actually, there is no second closing tag `</form>` at all.

Comment: if you go to http://www.liquidlizard.net/users/trainer and clear your cache then before doing anything else type belfast into the location input and hit return. The map centers on belfast but the marker doesn't come with it. If you then go and move the marker by dragging it then the marker and circle move. Weird. Any ideas?

Comment: Iget a javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setCenter' of undefined trainer:108`

Answer (score 1):

I get a javascript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setCenter' of undefined trainer:108

That is because you don't create the circle in the path that causes the issue, this should address that:

```
function geocode(){
 geocoder.geocode({
        address: $('#postcodeViolet').val()+' UK'
    }, function(results, status){
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
         var geoPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            map.setCenter(geoPoint);
            if (!!circle && !!circle.setCenter) circle.setCenter(geoPoint);
            marker.setPosition(geoPoint);
           $('#lattitude').val(geoPoint.lat());
           $('#longitude').val(geoPoint.lng());
        } else{
            alert("Can not geolocate this address.");
        }
    });
}
```